# The fundamental group of the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am following the lecture 25 provided by Wildberger talking about fundamental groups. Here I have a problem that I can not understand.
link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6f3I-RiWbk&t=490s at time 25:54

[My question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B878H.png)

What I know so far is that the fundamental group of a torus would be like Z × Z. And he use the rectangle to explain it, but I think it is not right. He said that you could have a path like $a$$b$$a^{−1}b^{−1}$, and you could shrink it to the constant loop like what the picture drew. How could this shrinking process happen? I think the interior of the torus is empty, so you can not shrink it like a circle. If the path can shrink to the base point, That means a circle could shrink to a point like a disk, right? So I am confused and I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the square (with identified edges) represents. The square corresponds to the "surface" of the torus, and the edges corresponds to loops on the torus as marked with colors on the picture. So the nullhomotopy of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ that on the square is just shrinking to one of the corners also translates to a nullhomotopy on the torus.

Another way to see that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ must be trivial in $\pi_1(\mathbb{T})$ is that $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, therefore any commutator vanishes.

Comment: So if a square which is not a disk  can shrink to one of the corners, I think the process is shrinking the square continuously. I mean for example, if the initial length is 1 and width is 2, then at t=0.5 we let it to be 0.5 and 1, finally at time t = 1, we let length and width both are zero, right? If the shrinking process is reasonable, why can't a circle do the same thing? You know we can pick one point on the circle, and we shrink the radius continuous, then finally a circle could shrink to a point. But I know it is not right because the circle is non-trivial.

Comment: The same works for any circle that you can draw in the square (without identifications). It does not work for one of the (drawn) generators of $\pi_1(\mathbb{T})$, because they are not circles when drawn on the square, so you cannot get a nullhomotopy on the torus from a nullhomotopy on the square.

Comment: Oh I got it. The square drawn is actually a rectangle disk so it can be shrunk to a point. But if you cut the torus to make a square, I think in this way you changed the topology structure of the torus, didn't you?

Comment: So as you said "so you cannot get a nullhomotopy on the torus from a nullhomotopy on the square". But actually the professor cut the torus to make the square, and on the square, he said we can shrink the path $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ to a point. I think the topology structure of the square and the torus are different, so we can not say that" Oh I found it nullhomotopic  on the square, so it must be nullhomotopic on the torus".

Comment: Unless we shrink the whole torus continuously, so the path could be shrunk continuously. Is that the idea what the professor want to express?

Comment: Of course the topology of the square and the torus are not equivalent. But there is a continous (surjective) map from the square to the torus (the projection), therefore, given a nullhomotopy on the square, you can project it down to a nullhomotopy of the projected loop on the torus.

Comment: Ok so the map is not bijective, right? Thank you so much!

Comment: Right, for example all the 4 corners are sent to the same point of the torus, and the identified edges become equal after projection. 
You're welcome.